# Given $A=B^2$. Let $p(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $q(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $B$. Prove $p(x^{2})=q(x) q(-x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

**Problem**: Let $n$ be an even positive integer, and let $A, B \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n}(\mathbf{R})$ such that $A=B^{2}$. Let $p(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and let $q(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $B$. Prove that $p\left(x^{2}\right)=q(x) q(-x)$.

**Attempt**: $ \det(A-x) = \det(B^2-x) \iff \det(A-x^2) = \det(B^2 - x^2) = \det( (B-x)(B+x)  ) = \det(B-x) \det( B+x) \iff p(x^2) = q(x)q(-x) $.

I haven't used the fact that $ n $ is an even positive integer so my proof feels specious. I have no idea if it's right, do you think the proof's correct? if not then how'd one prove the theorem above?

Comment: $A, B \in \operatorname{Mat}_{2}(\mathbf{R})$ or $A, B \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n}(\mathbf{R})$?

Comment: The question is from an old exam and I think you're right because otherwise I don't know what $ n $ refers to besides the fact that it's a number. I'll edit

Comment: The proof as it is looks correct to me, but remember to write $A - xI$ rather than $A - x$, as $A$ is a matrix while $x$ is a scalar

Comment: Your proof looks fine to  me. But there could be a difference between your definition of ch. polynomial and theirs. Perhaps $p(x)=det (x-A)$. In that case you need $n$ to be even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be the complex eigenvalues of $B$. Then we know that $\lambda_1^2,...,\lambda_n^2$ be the complex eigenvalues of $A$ since $A=B^2$.

Then
$$p(x^2) = (\lambda_1^2-x^2)...(\lambda_n^2-x^2)$$
and
$$q(x) =  (\lambda_1-x)...(\lambda_n-x).$$
Hence
$$p(x^2)=q(x).q(-x).$$

Here $n$ is an even positive integer ensures the sign of the equality.

Comment: Nice, I'd say: over $\mathbf{C}$ we can write $q(x)=\left(x-\lambda_{1}\right) \ldots\left(x-\lambda_{n}\right)$. Here $\lambda_{i} \in \mathbf{C}$ and need not be distinct. $$\begin{gathered}p\left(x^{2}\right)=\left(x^{2}-\lambda_{1}^{2}\right) \ldots\left(x^{2}-\lambda_{n}^{2}\right)=\left(x-\lambda_{1}\right) \ldots\left(x-\lambda_{n}\right)\left(x+\lambda_{1}\right) \ldots\left(x+\lambda_{n}\right)= \\=q(x)(-1)^{n}\left(-x-\lambda_{1}\right) \ldots\left(-x-\lambda_{n}\right)=q(x) q(-x)\end{gathered}$$where we used the fact that $n$ is even to write $(-1)^{n}=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach was fine. The key was that we may factor out $-1$ using the multilinearity of the determinant. That is, $$\det{(-xI-B)}=\det{((-1)(xI+B))}=(-1)^n\det(xI+B).$$

With an even $n$, we would be done.